# Magento BUG : Not able to delete Products Attributes Option/Labels?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, attribute-options, labels

If i delete one of the attributes values and save, keep the value exist, it's not delete.. how can i solve the issue magento error.

> Note:
>
> php.ini   =>   max_input_vars = 8000000 (master Value)
>
> .htaccess =>    php_value max_input_vars 8000000

How can i solve the issue?

Comment: Check consol and log file, Is there any things?

Comment: There is no releated errors...

Comment: @zus what error you get when you click on `save` buttton ?

Comment: There is no error if i delete one of the attributes options then click save the successful message will display but value not deleted

Comment: screen shot : https://imgur.com/6QZXrSl

Comment: after successful notification still not values deleted.....

Comment: @zus i did't got any notification, so next time follow as here : https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/970/list-of-standard-comments-for-review/1048#1048

Comment: for the question , check this once : [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549358/can-not-delete-magento-attribute-value-in-admin),  [link2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82120/not-able-to-update-or-delete-attribute-option-in-admin) , [link3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68406/cant-update-or-delete-attribute-options) @zus & one more : [link4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61287/delete-magento-attribute-value)

Comment: I have tried everything that you shared.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68868/discussion-between-zus-and-baby-in-magento).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68869/discussion-between-zus-and-baby-in-magento).

Answer (score 0):

Increasing max_input_vars is the answer, however maybe the change isn't taking effect.

I would create a file in the root of the site called `phpinfo.php` and add the following to it.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Save the file, browse to it (`www.domain.com/phpinfo.php`), and verify that the setting is being applied.

[image]

If it's not, you know that there is a configuration file somewhere overriding your current method to set this value.

Comment: You are telling how to check phpinfo details,  my error attributes values is not deleted?

Comment: @zus I'm telling you how to confirm whether or not your value override that you are trying to assign to `max_input_vars` is taking effect. In the end, the solution remains increasing the value of `max_input_vars`.